# How to get site link image to show up reliably when posting to social sites?

Tags: html, social-media

I hope this is the right kind of question for this forum.  I have seen [this post](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/121384/featured-image-wont-appear-when-sharing-to-facebook) but it didn't help or I didn't understand it well enough.

I'm trying to have the feature so that when a link (to a tour on our site) is posted to some social media site, I want an image for the tour and title/description to show up.

And I have spent some time on the og: settings.  But the images are just not showing up properly.

**OG settings**

These are the constructed **seattle link** og properties

```
    <meta property="og:type" content="website">
    <meta property="og:title" content="Explore Sunny Seattle">
    <meta property="og:description" content="We explored Seattle on the one day it was sunny!  Jump in!">
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://cdnm.worldalive.tours/us-east-1%3Afcaded1f-0911-4071-a4d8-8c047c7e3648/PPBL/pike+place+at+night+cover%2Ejpgmedium.jpg">
    <meta property="og:image:url" content="https://cdnm.worldalive.tours/us-east-1%3Afcaded1f-0911-4071-a4d8-8c047c7e3648/PPBL/pike+place+at+night+cover%2Ejpgmedium.jpg">
    <meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://cdnm.worldalive.tours/us-east-1%3Afcaded1f-0911-4071-a4d8-8c047c7e3648/PPBL/pike+place+at+night+cover%2Ejpgmedium.jpg">
    <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg">
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="800">
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="436">
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://worldalive.tours/tourbeta/5da7af5c30a71c1a6d1b8a76">
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="-">
    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
```

These are the constructed **Grand Canyon link** og properties.

```
    <meta property="og:type" content="website">
    <meta property="og:title" content="The Grand Canyon">
    <meta property="og:description" content="Explore the greatest canyon on earth!">
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://cdnm.worldalive.tours/us-east-1%3Afcaded1f-0911-4071-a4d8-8c047c7e3648/Grand+Canyon/cover%2Ejpgmedium.jpg">
    <meta property="og:image:url" content="https://cdnm.worldalive.tours/us-east-1%3Afcaded1f-0911-4071-a4d8-8c047c7e3648/Grand+Canyon/cover%2Ejpgmedium.jpg">
    <meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://cdnm.worldalive.tours/us-east-1%3Afcaded1f-0911-4071-a4d8-8c047c7e3648/Grand+Canyon/cover%2Ejpgmedium.jpg">
    <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg">
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="800">
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="436">
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://worldalive.tours/tourbeta/5db750c7e8f3f8710e8f2916">
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="-">
    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
```

**Twitter**

On twitter I can post this link

https://worldalive.tours/tourbeta/5da7af5c30a71c1a6d1b8a76

and the image [shows up](https://twitter.com/WorldAliveTours/status/1191072725168640000?s=20).

But this other link doesn't bring up the image when posted on twitter.

https://worldalive.tours/tourbeta/5db750c7e8f3f8710e8f2916

**Reddit**

Same thing as twitter. The Grand Canyon tour won't show the correct image but the seattle tour will.

https://www.reddit.com/user/worldalivedottours

**Facebook**

When I use the [sharing debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/), it sometimes works but I get an error message:

```
Provided og:image, https://cdnm.worldalive.tours/us-east-1%3Afcaded1f-0911-4071-a4d8-8c047c7e3648/PPBL/pike+place+at+night+cover%2Ejpgmedium.jpg could not be downloaded. This can happen due to several different reasons such as your server using unsupported content-encoding. The crawler accepts deflate and gzip content encodings.
```

And when I dig into that I am unable to find anything conclusive. One suggests zipping the content but its already a jpeg.  compression doesn't make sense.

When I post the link, it didn't bring up the images before, but now it does.  However when I look at summaries of the posts it's not using those images but another one from the site (the banner).

https://www.facebook.com/worldalivetours/

I feel like I'm missing either something really small - or something really big.

Any ideas as to what I might be doing wrong?

It seems that there is quite a [deep history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855361/fb-opengraph-ogimage-not-pulling-images-possibly-https) but there are a lot of "this worked for me" that I have tried with no luck.